# Vue.js -- How to prevent data modification between components

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js, point-of-sale

I must say I'm still pretty new to Vue.js.

I build a Point of Sale system with the help of [this tutorial](http://alexsears.com/article/create-pos-system-in-vuejs-part-1/).
I have made some modifications to it, for example the items are 
fetched with an api call and you now can edit the price of an item in the transaction. It also required some fixing after updating to latest vue version, for example v-repeat to v-for etc.

Now I have a problem that is if you edit the price of an item in the transaction
it also changes the price of the item in the item list where you click to add the items.

Due to reasons I can't provide a whole image of the app or large parts of code.

[Here's a screencap trying to explain what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr7xK.png)

In the item list template the items are rendered from `items` array with `v-for`.

In the transaction template the items are rendered from `itemList` array with `v-for`.
To clarify: `itemList` array contains the items added to the transaction.

I can't understand why this is happening or better yet how to prevent it. I can consider providing parts of the code if you need it.

**EDIT:**

In the comments Hector guessed that I'm referencing the same array in both of the templates, but that is not the case.

In the item list component I reference the `items` array  by passing a prop.

```
<item-list :items="items" :add="onItemClick"></item-list>
```

In the transaction component I reference the `lineItems` array by passing a prop.

```
<transaction :items="lineItems" :edit-number-of-items="editNumberOfItems" :edit-price-each="editPriceEach" :edit-total-qty="editTotalQty" :edit-taxed-price="editTaxedPrice" :editing="editing" :remove-item="removeItem"></transaction>
```

The first three cells of the transaction table:

```
<tbody>
                <tr v-for="item in items">
                    <!-- Code -->
                    <td>{{ item.item.id }}</td>
                    <!-- Name -->
                    <td>
                        <span>{{ item.item.name }}</span>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Price Each -->
                    <td>
                        <span class="editable-item" v-if="!item.editingPriceEach" @click="editPriceEach(item)">{{ item.item.priceEach }}</span>
                        <input v-if="item.editingPriceEach" @keyup.enter="editPriceEach(item)" type="text" v-model="item.item.priceEach" autofocus>
                        <button v-if="item.editingPriceEach" @click="editPriceEach(item)">OK</button>
                    </td>
```

In `<tr v-for="item in items">` `items` is referring to the prop name `items` not the array called `items` in the data option.

Also for example the function `editPriceEach` passed to the transaction component as a prop looks like this:

```
editPriceEach: function (lineItem) {
        lineItem.editingPriceEach = !lineItem.editingPriceEach;
}
```

As you can see it triggers the `editingPriceEach` property which is then used in the `onItemClick` function. It's used to add the items from the item list to the transaction:

```
onItemClick: function (item) {
        var found = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.lineItems.length; i++) {
            if (this.lineItems[i].item === item) {
                this.lineItems[i].numberOfItems++;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            this.lineItems.push({
                item: item,
                numberOfItems: 1,
                editingNumberOfItems: false,
                editingName: false,
                editingPriceEach: false,
                editingTaxedPrice: false,
                editingTotalQty: false
            });
        }
  },
```

Thank you for your patience with the small amount of code.

Comment: Probably you are referencing the same array in both places, so when you change something in one place, it changes in the other one. But we are completely at lost with this amount of information/code.

Comment: I edited the post and added more code!

Comment: @HectorLorenzo Do you have any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: "items is referring to the prop name items not the array called items in the data option".  Do you have both a data property called 'items' and a prop called 'items' in this component? I could see that causing issues